# Does MySQL support's creation of hidden column?

Tags: mysql

Is there any option in MySQL DB to create hidden/invisible columns in a table via CREATE/ALTER TABLE SQL, just like Oracle.

Comment: @Strawberry this is not the duplicate question. That question is to make it invisible in his java code/removing from the model.

Comment: I guess my point is really that you can undertake some basic research for yourself, and then come back when you have a question that fits with what SO is all about.

Comment: I had already made sufficient research before posting question. Do you have any answer for this question?